# Get content between characters in JavaScript with regex, and replace them with a variable string

Tags: javascript

I'm looking on how to replace some text between special characters (percentage symbols, in this example) by something else. There are a few answers here that manage to do that, but I need something extra on it, that's making it more difficult for me to find out how.

Let's say I have this string:

```
"![an image from my attributes](%image%)"
```

I want to replace `%image%` to something stored in a variable `image` somewhere. The problem is: I don't know which variables exists beforehand.

So I would need to parse each string between the '%%', check for a variable and if that exists, replace it with something else.

I managed to get what I want by doing this:

```js
const insertAttributeLinks = (markdown, post) => {
  let alter = markdown;
  const regexp = /[^%%]+(?=%)/g;
  const matches = markdown.match(regexp) || [];
  matches.forEach((match, index) => {
    if (index % 2 !== 0) {
     // So it just gets the actual string I want to replace;
      alter = alter.replace(`%${match}%`, post.attributes[match]?.value);
    }
  });
  return alter;
  };
  
const markdown = 'this is an example: ![](%image%) ![](%image_2%) ![](%image_3%)';
const post = {
  attributes: {
    image: {
      value: 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/5ef5d627-c162-4309-ab47-e09f6b411883'
    },
    image_2: {
      value: 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/MBZuMSqKlqHC4lDIci/giphy.gif'
    },
    image_3: {
      value: 'https://www.icegif.com/wp-content/uploads/rickroll-icegif-5.gif'
    }
  }
}

console.log(insertAttributeLinks(markdown, post));
```

But I'm afraid that, the way it is now, I'm parsing the mardown three times, changing just one variable each time, and that might get out of hand. I'm not specially happy with that "if" there. What would you advise?

Comment: Could you kindly explain what do you mean by "with multiple {} tags, I'll be parsing the string over and over again"?

Comment: Sure. Sorry! There was a typo. It should be '%%' tags. I meant that if the markdown has multiple instances of text between the percentage symbols, I would read all the string, and replace each instance, each time. Did that make it more clear?

Comment: I tried to make it simpler in the example. I'm changing it.

Comment: I'd advise to use your current approach (which looks perfectly functional), and only return to reengineer it if it becomes a performance bottleneck in practice. I would imagine it would take an enormous input string with many %% tags to cause any significant lag!

Comment: How about we go through the markdown input only once while replacing each `%placeholder%`? Is that what you want?

Comment: @h-sifat. Yes! :)

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo then kindly provide a larger markdown and attributes object example with what I can work with.

Comment: @h-sifat, I hope the example is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution for the example. We go through the markdown and if we find any placeholder we call the `replacer` function to get the value of that placeholder.

```js
const post = {
  attributes: {
    image: {
      value: "http://blabla.com/image1.gif",
    },
    image_2: {
      value: "http://blabla.com/image2.gif",
    },
    image_3: {
      value: "http://blabla.com/image3.gif",
    },
  },
};

// getPlaceholder -- Added later for making this code reusable
const getPlaceholder = (placeholder) => {
  const value = post.attributes[placeholder]?.value;
  // Call any error logger here if needed
  if (!value) throw new Error(`The value for "${placeholder}" doesn't exist`);
  return value;
};

const markdown =
  "this is an example: ![](%image%) ![](%image_2%) ![](%image_3%)";
// if it's only for image tags then
// chage the regex to : /!\[[^\]]*\]\(%([^%]+)%\)/g and modify the replacer
// function yourself
const pattern = /%([^%]+)%/g;

const replacer = (getPlaceholder) => (match, placeholder) =>
  getPlaceholder(placeholder);

const newMarkdown = markdown.replace(pattern, replacer(getPlaceholder));
// Dont forget to pass getPlaceholderfunc --------^
console.log(newMarkdown);
```

Comment: That's cool! Just one question: Why you didn't have to use the `replaceAll` method? Is that because the regExp is already global?

Comment: Exactly. The global flag matches all the instances.

Comment: You should really consider to fix that Regex. If someone has `%a%` in its markdown - that's a valid text and should not be considered or specially not throw random new Errors.

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan I'm really new to regex. Should I also check for the parentheses? Kindly give me some hint.

Comment: Also I might suggest to limit a function specificity @RaphaelAleixo - `post.attributes[placeholder]` are not things you want inside a function.

Comment: @h-sifat if the expected markdown is for images (start with `!`) a better regex would be https://regex101.com/r/ktrDWK/1 (see how `%t%` is not put into the mix) - if the `!` is not necessary, you can remove it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan should I make that `post.attributes[placeholder]` line more generic? How about `getPlaceHolderValue(placeholder)` and it will be up to the user to implement the `getPlaceHolderValue` function. And what about the regex? should I make it `/\(%([^%]+)%\)/g` ?

Comment: I would change the `data`. `value` is redundant. Document that the `replacer` function accepts an Object of `property: "value"` pairs, and yes, make it generic like: `replacer(obj)` and use like `replacer(post.attributes)` instead of hardcoding irrelevant names into a function. That way the function can be reused. `const url = post.attributes[placeholder]?.value;` would become a more general `const url = obj[placeholder];`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion. I learned a lot. I'll be updating my code shortly.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The image use is the example I found, but I would be parsing every %variable%, so h-sifat's regExp was working perfectly. :) Also, I don't have how to change the data.

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo simple: instead of `image: {value: "http://blabla.com/image1.gif",},` this is all you need: `image: "http://blabla.com/image1.gif",` - well, unless you have other properties in that child Object :)

Comment: @RokoC.BuljanWhat I meant is this data is coming from somewhere I can't access. I could remap on the client side it to what you are suggesting, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo in that case it's OK. - It all depends. I like to have reusable functions, that do what they say. Not to have to write again a function that I could have easily reused. So I would remap. But it all depends.

Comment: Just so you know, this what I ended up with, after your help:

```
const replaceMarkdownWithAttributes = (markdown, post) => {
  const pattern = /%([^%]+)%/g;
  return markdown.replace(pattern, (match, placeholder) => get(post, `attributes[${placeholder}].value`, placeholder));
};
```

Using lodash 'get' to treat the error (leaving the placeholder if can find a match in the post attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 cents with a better regex and a smaller function that does not accounts for strings like i.e: `%test%` since that should not be a *positive match* for replacement:

```js
/**
 * Replace Markdown's Image palceholder ![](%this%) with a property value.
 * @param {String} markdown Markdown String
 * @param {Object} attr Object with attribute: "value" replacements
 */
const MD_replaceImgValue = (markdown, attr) => markdown.replace(
  /(?<=!\[[^\]]*\]\()%([^%]+)%(?=\))/g, (m, p) => attr[p] || m
);



const markdown = `[Keep this as is](%unknown%) I like
this ![an image from my attributes](%image%) and 
also here's another ![Foo bar baz](%image_2%).
For example ![Lorem](%image_3%)`;

const post = {
  attributes: {
    image:   {value: 'https://example.com/img1.png'},
    image_2: {value: 'https://example.com/img2.png'},
    image_3: {value: 'https://example.com/img3.png'}
  }
};

// Modify slightly the post data to accommodate for our needs 
const attr = Object.entries(post.attributes)
  .reduce((a, [k,v]) => (a[k] = v.value, a), {});

// Test:
console.log(MD_replaceImgValue(markdown, attr));
```

here's the **[Regex101.com demo example](https://regex101.com/r/ktrDWK/2)**

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
let file = "![an image from my attributes](%image%) ![an image from my attributes](%image%) ![an image from my attributes](%image%)"

file = file.split("%image%")

for (let i = 1; i < file.length; i = i + 2) {
  file.splice(i,0, "IMAGE URL HERE")
}

file = file.join("")

console.log(file)
```

Edit: this is good for just replacing every %image% tag with something different. I see now that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: You missed to use the Object `attributes`. Why?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I realize now the format is %whatever the image name is% not just %image%. So the best method is the accepted answer. This answer is more for the question title.

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions for this so this is will be like this code.

````cs
String.replace(/%\w%/,new string)
```

This is basic concept for your problem so you can change regex any way.
````

Comment: I am using them already. :) If you check my code you'll see it. The problem is that the string to be replaced is based on what the regexp finds. I found a way to do it, but I was looking for ways to make it better. :)

Comment: try this ```c# var pattern = /%\w*%/g
const images=markdown.match(pattern)
```
now you can use your fiteration